# Can I return to a class when multiclassing?

Tags: multi-classing

What I mean is, if I take 3 levels in rogue, then 1 in fighter, can I take another level in rogue again, as if continuing from level 3 as a rogue to a level 4 after I dipped a level in fighter?

Comment: What game (and edition or version, if applicable) are you playing? You can [edit] in the tag, for example dnd-5e; This is necessary in order to answer your question. That said, welcome to the site! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and you can visit the [help] if you have more questions.

Comment: @qazwsx Edits bump a question into the reopen queue only once per closure ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239443/311001)). Given that, when a question that lacks dignificant reopen-necessary information--like system--I like to hold off on editing for readability until we've got the necessary information. Otherwise the question gets enqueued for reopening when it's very unlikely it'll benefit from that.